# Set foreign key of a table to two target columns in same target table PostgreSQLl

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-11

I am creating a table "line" that has a "startpoint" column and "endpoint" column these columns should be filled by the name of these points, that is in the table "points" in column "point name". I am trying to set a foreign key from points table to line: one for the startpoint column and the other to endpoint column, but both referenced to the same column in points table called "point name".But it didn't work.
How can I do it?
Note that I am using Postgresql version 11.6
this the code :

```
'create table public.line(
    lineid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('line_lineid_seq'::regclass),
    linetype character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    networkname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    startpointname character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    endpointname character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT endpoint FOREIGN KEY (endpointname)
        REFERENCES public.points (pointsname) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT startpoint FOREIGN KEY (startpointname)
        REFERENCES public.points (pointsname) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT length CHECK (length_m > 0::double precision),
    CONSTRAINT diameter CHECK (diameter_m > 0::double precision)
    );'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the code you tried

Comment: It is good to give your wrong code. But it is not a helpful to try to describe what you want your code to do by describing your wrong code. We can read your wrong code for that, and your wrong code doesn't tell us what it's supposed to be but isn't. Explain what you want your code to accomplish, like what values in one table have to appear where in what other table. Also "it didn't work" is not helpful. Say exactly what happened & research error messages. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a table "line" that has a "startpoint" column and "endpoint" column
>
> [...]
>
> I am trying to set a foreign key from `points` table to `line`

I think that you want things the other way around: you should have foreign keys in `lines` that reference the `points` table.

Consider:

```
create table points (
    point_id int primary key
);

create table lines (
    line_id int primary key,
    startpoint int references points(point_id),
    endpoint int references points(point_id)
)
```

Comment: yeah that is it ,I will try your solution